# Creating A Hue on iOS

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I've had a client approach me with a very interesting programming request: To create a red hue that is permanent on the iPhone. You launch the app, turn on the hue, then while the app is running in the background, all of iOS will have a red tint. Obviously this would have to be on a jailbroken device, which I have no experience with.

The approach I want to take is putting a transparent red image on the screen, and allow for everything in the background to be pressed. Is this even possible? What would be the best approach?

I know this exists for iOS apps:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

But how can I do this to the entire OS?

Comment: Give your client a pair of rose-colored glasses -- that will work even on non-jailbroken devices. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a very simple jailbreak tweak. First you will have to learn to write a jailbreak tweak, start here: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Getting_Started

Skipping ahead and pretending that you already have your environment setup and able to build a tweak, you will hook into SpringBoard at the point where it is finished loading the UI(ex. applicationDidFinishLaunching:) and add a new window at a very high level(ex. 10,000). With the app or preference bundle to turn it on the hue you will just setBackgroundColor: of that window.

Comment: Thank you sir. Would it be possible to do this in Xcode?